# Traefik 2 set passHostHeader globally and not per service?

Tags: traefik

I'm using traefik internally as a gateway and thus want to always have `passtHostHeader: false` for default as to not always have it repeatedly set on each service.

I looked through the

- [ENVs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/reference/static-configuration/env/)
- [cli arguments](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/reference/static-configuration/cli/) &
- [dynamic configuration reference](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/reference/dynamic-configuration/file/)

but to no avail.

Is there a way to achieve this?

my `dynamic-file.yml`

```
  routers:
    ext-service-router:
      rule: "PathPrefix(`/ext-service`)
      service: ext-service-service


  services:
    ext-service-service:
      loadBalancer:
        passHostHeader: false # I want this to be the default and not need to set it
        servers:
          - URL: "https://my-ext-service.example.com"
```